# Testing an internal fluent API

Tags: java, fluent-interface

I have designed a fluent interface to retrieve list elements.

One call can be like:

```
repo.actives().sortedByCode().values();
```

The main avantage is the readability of the code.

The call `values()` returns a `List<OfWhatIExpect>`. The previous calls (actives(), sortedByCode(), ...) return a ListResult managing the fluent API.

I'm working on how to test the API call. Depending on the use case, I must be sure that the caller used the `actives()` API for example.

Any ideas on how to manage that?